# Escaping a Blackhole

Tags: antimatter, hawking-radiation, matter

On reading hawking radiation, I know that either a matter or an anti-matter is able to escape a black hole, causing it to evaporate away soon.

On this thought, I am curious that would it be possible for the Earth to create a spaceship with matter and a spaceship with anti-matter in a vacuum and send them into space, aiming at a black hole aiming that it will get information human wants and drive back. Why would it not be possible for human to do that (don't talk about the money)? Since Hawking Radiation can theoretically escape a black hole, so will the space ship!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not follow that since Hawking radiation can leave the black hole that spacecraft can.

Hawking radiation is due to the strongly curved spacetime near the black hole and how it interacts in peculiar ways with quantum fields. The standard popular science explanation that virtual particle-antiparticle pairs pop up, one is absorbed and the other escapes, is a serious oversimplification - virtual particles [are not really real](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206877/are-virtual-exchange-particles-real-or-just-mathematical) but describe what the quantum fields *do* pretty well. In any case, it is not so much that anything leaves from inside the event horizon as a process that happens just outside it.