# Meson production not originating from a collision

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

Does anyone know a process that produces mesons other than through collisions from particle accelerators and cosmic ray experiments?

Thanks
DaPhys

Comment: Not enough information, what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

All mesons are unstable and most have quite short half-lives even by particle physics standards, so they are only to be found (as on-shell particles<sup>1</sup>) in the presence of energetic events. And if you look closely enough the process that creates them is essentially<sup>2</sup> always one of banging two particles together pretty hard.

---

<sup>1</sup> That is, [I am excluding virtual particles from the discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162845/what-physical-evidence-is-there-that-subatomic-particles-pop-in-and-out-of-exist).

<sup>2</sup> I'm ignoring Hawking radiation and related processes as possible sources here. Not sure that this is entirely fair, but I can't speak authoritatively on that subject.